# Android- How to title Google Maps markers with its own coordinates?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Currently, my marker setting is this, and the marker title is just "marked" for now:

```
final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
markerOptions.position(latLng);
markerOptions.title("Marked");
markerOptions.draggable(false);
markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker3));
mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

How can I title the markers as the coordinates they are placed on?

Answer (score 0):

You should convert `latLng` to coordinates and the use `markerOptions.title(convertedCoordinates);`

Comment: How do I convert latLng to coordinates?

Comment: well, your `latLng` already has the `x` and `y` coordinates in it. You should look how to access it. Probably `latLng[0]` for `x` and `latLng[1]` for `y`